# Wordpress Nav Menu - How can I add a button element before every submenu ul?

Tags: wordpress

I want to add a button element before every submenu ul element in wordpress nav menu for toggling between submenus in mobile view. What I mean:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Category</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Category</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Category</a>
        <button type="button" class="toggle-btn">
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">SubCategory</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SubCategory</a></li>                     
            <li><a href="#">SubCategory</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>                 
</ul>
```

I tried using the walker class but had no success. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***add button before sub menu***

add walker class in wp_nav_menu "new Add_button_of_Sublevel_Walker"

```
<?php
            $header_menu_defaults = array(
                'theme_location'  => '',
                'menu'            => 'your menu name',
                'container'       => '',
                'container_class' => '',
                'container_id'    => '',
                'menu_class'      => '',
                'menu_id'         => '',
                'echo'            => true,
                'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
                'before'          => '',
                'after'           => '',
                'link_before'     => '',
                'link_after'      => '',
                'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
                'depth'           => 0,
                'walker'         => new Add_button_of_Sublevel_Walker
            );
            wp_nav_menu( $header_menu_defaults );
        ?>
```

add below function in function.php

```
/* Options Frame Work End Here */

class Add_button_of_Sublevel_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<button type='button' class='toggle-btn'>
            <span class='bar'></span>
            <span class='bar'></span>
            <span class='bar'></span>
        </button><ul class='submenu'>\n";
    }
    function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
    }
}
```